# Validating number in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to validate only numbers. I used below cord.But it doesn't work.

```
Public Function validateNumber(number) As Boolean
    Dim num As New Regex("^[0-9]{9}$")
    If num.IsMatch(number) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: `IsNumeric(value)`

Comment: I used IsNumaric but i want other method for it.

Comment: What is your input to the function? Also, doing `If num.IsMatch(number) Then` is redundant since `IsMatch` will return a boolean. Skip the `If`-statement and do it in one line: `Return num.IsMatch(number)`.

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: I want to input numbers and check it when click the save button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below regex...

```
   Dim num As New        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^\d+$")
   Return num.Match(number).Success
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ISnumeric(yourno)`  it will return true if it is a number , you can use bellow link for more info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1(v=vs.90).aspx